# iterate array and populate with json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the folowing code

```js
seriesTitles = ['depth', 'incline'];

var aSeries = { name: '', data: [{}] };

var seriesArray = [];

seriesTitles.forEach((element) => {
  aSeries.name = element;
  seriesArray.push(aSeries);
});
console.log(seriesArray);
```

But something is wrong. It seems to add the last item in the seriesTitles array twice!
The output I get is..

```
{"name": "incline","data": [{}]}

{"name": "incline","data": [{}]}
```

When I run the code I would expect to see..

```
{"name": "depth","data": [{}]}

{"name": "incline","data": [{}]}
```

I am new to javascript and am thrown by this. Can anyone please point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: You `push` the same thing, `aSeries`, multiple times, as opposed to making a *new* `aSeries` each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the working example:**

```js
let seriesTitles = ["depth", "incline"];

let seriesArray = [];

seriesTitles.forEach((element) => {
  // for every iteration  create new object
  let aSeries = { name: "", data: [{}] };
  aSeries.name = element;
  seriesArray.push(aSeries);
});

//
console.log(seriesArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because, the object literals in JavaScript are reference variables, and you are pushing the exact same object to the array. So, its like pushing the same address of the object multiple times. So, whenever you make any change somewhere, the whole array seems to change because all the objects are same. You can read more about it here https://academind.com/tutorials/reference-vs-primitive-values

You can create a copy of the object and then make changes to the properties and then push it to the array. You can use destructuring to make a copy.

```js
seriesTitles = ['depth', 'incline'];

var aSeries = { name: '', data: [{}] };

var seriesArray = [];

seriesTitles.forEach((element) => {
  aSeries.name = element;
  seriesArray.push({...aSeries});
});
console.log(seriesArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the `aSeries` twice, and happen to modify the `name`. If you want different `aSeries` objects, then either make a copy or change the scope and create it inside of the forEach.

You could make a copy using the spread operator:

```
seriesTitles = ['depth','incline']      
const seriesArray  = []
const aSeries = {name: '',data: [{}]};
seriesTitles.forEach(element => { // outer loop
  aSeries.name = element;
  seriesArray.push({...aSeries});    
})
console.log(seriesArray)
```

Or just move the declaration of the `aSeries` variable inside of the for loop, so that you instantiate a new one each time.

```
seriesTitles = ['depth','incline']      
const seriesArray  = []

seriesTitles.forEach(element => { // outer loop
  const aSeries =  {name: '',data: [{}]}
  aSeries.name = element;
  seriesArray.push(aSeries);    
})
console.log(seriesArray)
```